# How to make an Echo server with Bash?

Tags: bash, tcp, netcat

How to write a echo server bash script using tools like nc, echo, xargs, etc capable of simultaneously processing requests from multiple clients each with durable connection?

The best that I've came up so far is

```
nc -l -p 2000 -c 'xargs -n1 echo'
```

but it only allows a single connection.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04's `nc` has no `-c` option =( (`netcat-openbsd` package).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you use ncat instead of nc your command line works fine with multiple connections but (as you pointed out) without -p.

```
ncat -l 2000 -k -c 'xargs -n1 echo'
```

ncat is available at http://nmap.org/ncat/.

P.S. with the original the Hobbit's netcat (nc) the -c flag is not supported.

Update: -k (--keep-open) is now required to handle multiple connections.

Comment: Thanks! It works but with a minor change - we should use it without the "-p" option:
ncat -l 2000 -c 'xargs -n1 echo'

Comment: @BinWang updated. Follow douyw link below for further explanations

Comment: `xargs -n1 echo` splits up lines by whitespace, but `xargs -l1 echo` keeps lines intact.

Answer (score 35):

Here are some examples. [ncat simple services](http://nmap.org/ncat/guide/ncat-simple-services.html)

TCP echo server

```
ncat -l 2000 --keep-open --exec "/bin/cat"
```

UDP echo server

```
ncat -l 2000 --keep-open --udp --exec "/bin/cat"
```

Comment: Beware though, that with `--udp`, ncat will keep the "connections" open and if you don't want to hit the default limit of 100 connections, then you should either increase the maximum with the `--max-conns` option or let the "connections" die after an idle timeout that you can set with `--idle-timeout`.

Answer (score 22):

In case ncat is not an option, socat will also work:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:2000,fork EXEC:cat
```

The `fork` is necessary so multiple connections can be accepted. Adding `reuseaddr` to `TCP4-LISTEN` may be convenient.

Answer (score 2):

**`netcat` solution pre-installed in Ubunutu**

The `netcat` pre-installed in Ubuntu 16.04 comes from `netcat-openbsd`, and has no `-c` option, but the manual gives a solution:

```
sudo mknod -m 777 fifo p
cat fifo | netcat -l -k localhost 8000 > fifo
```

Then client example:

```
echo abc | netcat localhost 8000
```

TODO: how to modify the input string value? The following does not return any reply:

```
cat fifo | tr 'a' 'b' | netcat -l -k localhost 8000 > fifo
```

The remote shell example however works:

```
cat fifo | /bin/sh -i 2>&1 | netcat -l -k localhost 8000 > fifo
```

I don't know how to deal with concurrent requests simply however.

Answer (score 0):

what about...

```
#! /bin/sh

while :; do
/bin/nc.traditional -k -l -p 3342 -c 'xargs -n1 echo'
done
```

Comment: while :; do /bin/nc.traditional -k -l -p 3342 -c xargs -n1 echo ; done