# BASH catching <&3 into var

Tags: bash, var, netcat

Trying to understand how the <&3 redirect can be caught into a var in bash.

When I run the code below it stops at line 9 with the `MSG to SEND` being printed as if the `cat <&3` is being run without catching it in the var `myRcvMsg`. If I open another shell and nc on the port it continues to printout each line sent (this is what I want, just need to trap it rather than print it)

If I change line to `myRcvMsg="$(<&3)"` then lines 10,11 execute but no var prints out.

what am I doing wrong?

thx
Art

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting Script"
exec nc -p 18000 -l &
sleep 1                                  # wait for port to open
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/192.168.1.1/18000
echo "MSG to SEND" >&3
echo "MSG has been sent"
myRcvMsg="$(cat <&3)"
echo "MSG should have been RCV'd"
echo "This is the RCV msg:${myRcvMsg}"
```

Comment: Why are you using the `cat` program instead of the `read` shell builtin?

Answer (score 0):

Try to read from

```
myRcvMsg="$(cat /dev/fd/3)"
```

Comment: `/proc` is specific to Linux. `/dev/fd/3` should be acceptable to `bash`, regardless of what the file system actually provides.

Comment: @vanda I am using debian but get cat: /dev/fd/3: No such device or address. do I initialize it a different way before calling it?  thx Art.

Comment: @artvanderlay If your using linux try with `/proc/self/fd/3` in your script.

Answer (score 0):

The execution of nc puts it into listen mode, but it will write its output to stdout instead of echoing it back through the net. See [Echo server with bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375860/echo-server-with-bash) for ideas how to make it into an echo server.

On my machine I had to use 127.0.0.1 to get a connection.

Next problem is that you have to make sure that your message is not stuck in a buffer. While you wait on the out-end of &3 for nc to echo something, nc may not have actually seen your message. In my test the `$(cat <&3)` just hangs.

The following kind of works.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x
echo "Starting Script"
exec nc -p 18000 -l -c "xargs -n1 echo" &
sleep 1                                  # wait for port to open
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/18000
cat <&3 >ttt &
sleep 1
echo "MSG to SEND" >&3
echo "MSG has been sent"
sleep 1
myRcvMsg=$(cat ttt)
echo "MSG should have been RCV'd"
echo "This is the RCV msg:\"${myRcvMsg}\""
```

For more information, see http://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/shell/co-processes.hints, where the buffering problem is highlighted in *3/ Buffered Output problem*.