# Minimal example of "websocket wrapping" for web server using websockify

Tags: javascript, websocket, websockify

some webdev basic questions for a noob.

**background**: I have a javascript client that uses the *websocket* protocol, and a good old java server, which I'm perfectly able to interact with via `telnet`. I want them to be able to communicate to each other locally (passing strings would suffice).

For that, I definitely don't want to make deep changes in the client. I tried to adapt the server to *websocket* following [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_a_WebSocket_server_in_Java) guide before that, and even passed the handshake but it got pretty messy.

So at this point I believe that the best way to deal with this would be to serve through a TCP->WebSocket proxy like [websockify](https://github.com/novnc/websockify/wiki/websock.js). If I got the [explanation](https://github.com/novnc/websockify#wrap-a-program) right, it would "wrap" the server's process, opening the "upgraded" connection in a new port. And the *websocket* client should be able to directly speak to the server through that port. But I've been trying to implement this with different approaches without success, therefore my **questions**:

---

- **Is there a better way to deal with this problem? (that would explain google's sparseness, I can imagine this happens very often!)**
- **If "wrapping" is the best way and I got it right, how to implement it?**

---

**Implementation - edited**: For the sake of testing, I've tried to build a simple echo server:

- I'm running the very simple command line echo server suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8378448/4511978) post: `ncat -l 2000 -k -c xargs -n1 echo`. Talking to it via `telnet localhost 2000` returns the desired echo. So far so good.
- I installed [websockify](https://github.com/novnc/websockify#wrap-a-program) using `apt-get`,and run it as follows: `websockify 2023: 2000`, this should open the same server via a websocket connection on port 2023.
- At this point I'm still able to comunicate via `telnet localhost 2000`, but I'm not having that much luck with port 2023. This is what I tried so far:

  - Downloaded the [telsocket](https://github.com/lafikl/telsocket) binary, and called `./telsocket -url ws://127.0.0.1:2023`. **Response: `errrr dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2023: connection refused`**
  - Cloned [wssh](https://github.com/progrium/wssh) (a command line shell for websocket), which seems very promising. I was able to install it, but running `wssh -l localhost:2023` returns **`NameError: name 'PROTOCOL_SSLv3' is not defined`**. Apparently some problems with `gevent` (didn't look much further into that).
  - Tested the several examples in `websockify`'s repo, like [wstelnet](https://github.com/novnc/websockify/blob/master/wstelnet.html), or the ones in [tests](https://github.com/novnc/websockify/tree/master/tests). All of them got me a **code 400, message Invalid protocol selected**.

---

**Follow-up - edited**: Diving deeper into the websock.js and wstelnet.js [files](https://github.com/novnc/websockify/tree/master/include), I was able to get more specific results by issuing the following into the JS console:

```
ws = new Websock()
ws.open("ws://127.0.0.1:2023", "binary") // connects, proxy says: connecting to: :2000, Plain non-SSL (ws://) WebSocket connection, Version hybi-13, base64: 'False'
ws.send_string("hello server")           // send and wait for echo 
ws.get_rQ()                              // empty??
```

So, as you can see, I'm able to establish the connection, but still don't get an echo. The mistake might be as well in the server's side since every tool I tried is failing. Help! D:

---

**Remarks**: Since it is intended to work locally, I wouldn't care having either `ws` or `wss`. I also don't have a preferred way to do this as long as it is viable and works. In case it is relevant, I'm on Ubuntu15.10 + Firefox47.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

finally, I got the TCP echo server communicating with *websockify*'s [websocket telnet emulator](https://github.com/novnc/websockify-js/blob/master/wstelnet.html) through *websockify*'s proxy. This is how:

1. run the echo server `ncat -l 2000 -k -c 'xargs -n1 echo echoServer received'`
2. in a separate process, run the proxy: `websockify 2023 :2000`
3. clone the repo: `git clone https://github.com/novnc/websockify.git`, and make the following changes to [wstelnet.js](https://github.com/novnc/websockify-js/blob/master/include/wstelnet.js):

   3.1 changing the line `ws.open(uri)` to `ws.open(uri, "binary")` allowed to overcome the *code 400* problem.

   3.2 in the [definition of do_recv](https://github.com/novnc/websockify/blob/5b7f7224ed2b958d1fdc13d3f04330188d237cb6/include/wstelnet.js#L54) (this is a permalink), add the following line after the initial `var` statement: `arr = Array.from(arr);` this is a conversion to *Array* since *Uint8Array* didn't apparently support the `shift` method.
4. open [wstelnet.html](https://github.com/novnc/websockify-js/blob/master/wstelnet.html) with firefox, select **Host**: localhost, **Port:** 2023, no encryption, press **Connect** and type into the black field.

The screen should reply with `echoServer received: <YOUR_MESSAGE>`. [hurray!](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/success.png)

Comment: I'll leave this unaccepted for a while in case someone has a better suggestion for dealing with this problem. Many thanks to user kanaka for this amazing software

Comment: This blog confirms that this is a very good way to deal with this problem: https://barkingbogart.wordpress.com/2014/10/08/use-websockify-in-windows/
So after some weeks without further reactions I accept my own answer