# How to make a "same response" server with bash?

Tags: linux, netcat

I'm trying to set up a simple server that returns always the same response.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8378448) I've tried to use

```
ncat -l 2000 --keep-open --exec "/bin/echo 234"
```

but on the client it shows only once.

```
Ncat: Broken pipe.
```

If I use the UDP option (-u), it works as intended. So I'm guessing it's EOF's fault.

Is there a way to make it work as a reponse to the client's messages in TCP?

Comment: I guess you have to read the input before outputting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something as simple you could:

```
ncat -l 2000 --keep-open --exec "xargs -I{} echo 234"
```

I find also the following works:

```
ncat -l 2000 --keep-open --sh-exec "while read line; do echo 234; done"
```

or like:

```
ncat -l 2000 --keep-open --sh-exec "echo 234; cat >/dev/null"
```

Comment: I've tried the first one and I couldn't make it work, but the second one works well